# Powershell script to replace link:lalala.html[lalala] with xref:lalala.adoc[lalala] capture pattern and replace recursively

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a folder full of text documents in .adoc format that have some text in them. The text is following: `link:lalala.html[lalala]`. I want to replace this text with `xref:lalala.adoc[lalala]`. So, basically, just replace `link:` with `xref:`, `.html` with `.adoc`, leave all the rest unchanged.
But the problem is that `lalala` can be anything from a word to `../topics/halva.html`.

I definitely know that I need to use regex patterns, I previously used similar script. A replace directive wrapped in an object:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path *.adoc -file -recurse | ForEach-Object {

$lines = Get-Content -Path $PSItem.FullName -Encoding UTF8 -Raw

$patterns = @{
 '(\[\.dfn \.term])#(.*?)#' = '$1_$2_' ;
}
$option = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Singleline 

foreach($k in $patterns.Keys){
  $pat = [regex]::new($k, $option)
  $lines = $pat.Replace($lines, $patterns.$k)
}

$lines | Set-Content -Path $PSItem.FullName -Encoding UTF8 -Force

}
```

Looks like I need a different script since the new task cannot be added as just another object. I could've just replaced each part separately, using two objects: replace `link:` with `xref:`, then replace `.html` with `.adoc`.

But this can interfere with other links that end with `.html` and don't start with `link:`. In the text, absolute links usually don't have `link:` in the beginning. They always start with http:// or https://. And they still may or may not end with `.html`. So the best idea is to take the whole string `link:lalala.html[lalala]` and try to replace it with `xref:lalala.adoc[lalala]`.

I need the help of someone who knows regex and PowerShell, please this would save me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a pattern, you might use

```
\blink:(.+?)\.html(?=\[[^][]*])
```

- `\blink:` Match `link:`
- `(.+?)` Capture 1+ chars as least as possbile in group 1
- `\.html` match `.html`
- `(?=\[[^][]*])` Assert from an opening till closing square bracket at the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KlTqbv/1)

In the replacement use group 1 using `$1`

```
xref:$1.adoc
```

Example

```
$Strings = @("link:lalala.html[lalala]", "link:../topics/halva.html[../topics/halva.html]")
$Strings -replace "\blink:(.+?)\.html(?=\[[^][]*])",'xref:$1.adoc'
```

Output

```
xref:lalala.adoc[lalala]
xref:../topics/halva.adoc[../topics/halva.html]
```